# mpg321 doesn't autoplay songs

Tags: osx

I'm using mpg321 on OSX and I just try to play my songs with mpg321 *.mp3.  It plays fine but doesn't play the next song automatically.  I have to press some key for it to play which is kind of annoying.  How can I make it so it plays automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I justed tried this on a Fedora Linux box using `mpg321` version 0.2.11 and the following worked:

#### specific files

```
% mpg321 /path/to/file1.mp3 /path/to/file2.mp3
```

#### *.mp3

```
% mpg321 *.mp3
```

#### directory used

```
% ls
track_01.mp3 track_02.mp3 track_03.mp3 track_04.mp3 track_05.mp3 track_06.mp3
track_07.mp3 track_08.mp3 track_09.mp3 track_10.mp3 track_11.mp3 track_12.mp3
track_13.mp3 track_14.mp3 track_16.mp3 track_18.mp3 track_19.mp3
```

I would suspect that either the directory you're doing this in has more mp3 files than can your shell can handle when the **'*.mp3'** get's expanded to all the files that are there, or that there is an issue with your particular version of `mpg321`.

Comment: Upgrading it with brew upgrade mpg321 fixed it :)

Comment: Great! Please mark my answer as the accepted one so that others know the question has been resolved/answered.